# How can I find the trailers from my new DLC?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I have just downloaded a trailer pack for Euro Truck Simulator 2 and I cannot find them in-game. Where should I look?

Answer (score 2):

**For official DLC** will be automatically activated and you should see the content in your game. Drive to maintenance and check your paint jobs there (*not* your own garage!)

**For mods** you will need to go to your profiles, click edit and enable all of the necessary mods. You should now see the content in your game. Again, remember to check at a maintenance garage (again, *not* your own garage).

Answer (score 0):

First you must edit your current profile and enable mod you have downloaded. Before you will click "Continue", click "Edit" at the active profile and enable this mod. In case of *Trailer pack with Realistic Textures* you will not see any new cargo, but you will see only new textures at trailers. I hope it helps.